# Bootstrap-vue-next and Vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, modal-dialog, vue-component, vite

I have a problem with building process. I have a modal `b-modal` that it's a component am using in Vuejs 3 and when I am in development I run `npm run dev` which is fine because there is no problem but when I run `npm run prod` for asset building for production purposes the modal is not working and yet it was working in production. My project is Laravel/vuejs

I tried changing versions of both vite and bootstrap-vue-next and still not working in production.

I can't really understand why there is such behaviour and I even dug into maybe possibility of using webpack instead of vite and still not working at all.

Package.json:

````
{

    "private": false,

    "scripts": {

        "dev": "vite",

        "prod": "vite build"

    },

    "devDependencies": {

        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",

        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",

        "axios": "^0.25.0",

        "lodash": "^4.17.19",

        "postcss": "^8.1.14",

        "sass": "^1.56.1",

        "vue": "^3.3.4"

    },

    "dependencies": {

        "@anivive/vue3-form-wizard": "^1.0.1",

        "@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown": "^2.1.1",

        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^36.0.1",

        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^4.0.1",

        "@fullcalendar/bootstrap5": "^6.1.5",

        "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.5",

        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.5",

        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.5",

        "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.5",

        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.5",

        "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^6.1.5",

        "@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs": "^1.3.0",

        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",

        "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.9.0",

        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.47",

        "@vueform/multiselect": "^2.6.1",

        "@vueform/slider": "^2.1.7",

        "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0",

        "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0",

        "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",

        "bootstrap-vue-next": "^0.6.7",

        "dropzone": "^6.0.0-beta.2",

        "fullcalendar": "^6.1.4",

        "i18n": "^0.15.1",

        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.4",

        "leaflet": "^1.9.3",

        "maska": "^1.5.0",

        "metismenujs": "^1.4.0",

        "simplebar-vue": "^2.3.1",

        "simplebar-vue3": "^0.2.0",

        "sweetalert2": "^11.7.3",

        "vite": "^4.4.9",

        "vite-plugin-static-copy": "^0.13.1",

        "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",

        "vue-cropperjs": "^5.0.0",

        "vue-draggable-next": "^2.1.1",

        "vue-easy-lightbox": "^1.15.0",

        "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",

        "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",

        "vue-loader": "^17.0.1",

        "vue-router": "^4.1.6",

        "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",

        "vue3-carousel": "^0.2.13",

        "vue3-datepicker": "^0.3.4",

        "vue3-dropzone": "^2.0.1",

        "vue3-google-map": "^0.15.0",

        "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",

        "vuex": "^4.0.2"

    }

}
``` and my vote.config.js is
````

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({

```
build: {

    manifest: true,

    // rtl: true,

    outDir: 'public/build/',

    cssCodeSplit: true,

    rollupOptions: {

        output: {

            assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {

                if (assetInfo.name.endsWith('.css')) {

                    // Rename CSS files with a unique hash

                    return `css/[name].[hash].css`;

                }

                return `assets/[name].[hash][extname]`;

            },

            entryFileNames: 'js/[name].[hash].js',

        },

    },

    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 2000, // Adjust this limit as needed

    manualChunks: {

        // Specify your chunk names and their entry points

        'chunk-vendor': ['vue'],

        'chunk-app': ['app.js', 'app-rtl.scss'],

        'chunk-bootstrap': ['bootstrap.scss'],

        'chunk-icons': ['icons.scss'],

    },

},

plugins: [

    laravel({

        input: [

            'resources/sass/app.scss',

            'resources/sass/app-rtl.scss',

            'resources/sass/bootstrap.scss',

            'resources/sass/icons.scss',

            'resources/js/app.js',

        ],

        refresh: true,

    }),

    vue({

        template: {

            transformAssetUrls: {

                base: null,

                includeAbsolute: false,

            },

        },

    }),

    viteStaticCopy({

        targets: [

            {

                src: 'resources/fonts',

                dest: ''

            },

            {

                src: 'resources/images',

                dest: ''

            },

        ],

    })

],

resolve: {

    alias: {

        vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',

        // '@': '/resources/sass'

    },

},
```

});

```
Code snippet for the modal is:
```

```
        <div class="card-body">

            <form action="javascript:void(0)" >

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-4">

                        <div class="mb-3">

                            <label for="name">Name</label>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name65" placeholder="Enter Device Name" v-model="obj.name" @input="validateName"/>

                            <span v-if="validationErrors.nameError" class="text-danger">{{validationErrors.nameError}}</span>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">

                        <div class="mb-3">

                            <label for="reg_no6">Unique ID</label>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reg_no" placeholder="Enter ID emitted by the object" v-model="obj.unique_id" @input="validateRegistration" />

                            <span v-if="validationErrors.unique_idError" class="text-danger">{{validationErrors.unique_idError}}</span>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <div class="text-end">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveObj">Submit</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </form>

        </div>

    </b-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by the minification of certain CSS file. Vite minified app.css and now it included only one file in the head section of the html page instead of both the minified version of the files.